# Facebook AppRequests + Browser Compatibility

Tags: java, facebook, servlets, apprequests, facebook-app-requests

I have a web based application that requires the functionality to "share the application" to the logged-in user's friends.

I generate a URL for this (see below) and it works, as it should, in:

Desktop Browsers

Android Chrome Browser

Android Firefox displays a blank screen while The "Internet" Browser (default shipped browser with most Android devices <4.4) shows:

> ---
>
> > "**Server Error**
> > The website encountered an error while retrieving [URL]. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
>
> ---

The URL generated (after www -> m redirecting) is :

> > https://m.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=[APP_ID]&message=[MESSAGE]&redirect_url=[CALLBACK URL]

Another observation is that if I force the mobile browsers to render as a desktop web page, and replace m with www, it works fine...

I am using Java Servlettes(with [RestFB](http://restfb.com/)), jQuery (Base+Mobile) + HTML

Would anyone know what I am missing for the other browsers? It seems odd that it works in some and not in others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone's reference, it seems, like at this point in time, that I was trying to achieve something unrealisble with the Facebook API. I have since changed to the JavaScript SDK for Facebook, and the problem has disappeared.

Smacking my head why I initially thought using the SDK would be overkill - so much easier to use!

Answer (score 0):

Try www, not m and add at the end of url `&display=touch`.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work. The mobile browser will automatically redirect to m. If I force desktop views in the mobile browser it works, but for the application itself, this solution isn't viable.